# Does exist any C# documentation standards?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation

I made program in c# (ASP.NET) and I have to document it by current standards. Does exists any c# documentation standards? I tried to find it on Google, but no answer. Is there any standard? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what type of documentation you need to do? You can do XML comment documenting in your code as an example. You can use swagger to generate documentation for your apis as well.

Comment: Check out _Doxygen_.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/